# Session Timeout in PHP

Tags: php, session

I included a php syntax in my project which is:

```
if((time() - $_SESSION['time']) > 1800){
    echo "<script> alert('Session has expired.'); </script>";
    header("location:logout.php");
}
```

Which automatically logs out the user in a span of 30minutes.
But whenever i change my page it directly destroy the session.

already initialize the $_SESSION['time'] in my login script which is

```
if($_SESSION['userid'] = logIn($login)){
    $_SESSION['time']  = time();
    echo 'success';
}
```

Here is a sample link from my navigation bar

```
<li class="dashboard-item">
    <a href="collections.php">
        <i class="dashboard-icon mdi-hardware-watch flow-text"></i>
        <p class="item-label center">Collection</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: 1. Are you starting the session in every script? 2. You cannot user a `header()` redirect after you have outputted anything to the browser. 3. You should check if the `$_SESSION['time']` variable exists before you use it.

Comment: I get it. i only include the session_destroy(); and not the header() redirect and it somehow works. :D

Comment: Well, output the value of `$_SESSION['time']` at every step and see if it is what you expect. – Also, you really want to log out the user exactly 30 minutes after they logged in, regardless of whether they were actively using the site or not?! That's... unusual.

Comment: Yes that would be my second problem. Can i somehow renew the value of $_SESSION['time']? whenever a user click / leave to a page?

Comment: If you want to destroy the session after 30 minutes **of inactivity**, don't bother with this manual way of doing it. Simply configure your session backend and the session cookie to expire automatically after 30 minutes, done! This is functionality which is already built into session handling, you just need to tweak it to your needs. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime